# .NET Razor + Bootstrap How to split a very long element declaration into multiple lines of code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When declaring some bootstrap element using the Razor syntax, how would go about to split it on multiple lines?

I have a very long line of code which looks pretty stupid when on a single line.
Here is the line of code that I want to split:

```
@f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.EquipmentItem.Fields[field.Key].FieldValue).Id(field.Key.ID.ToString()).HtmlAttributes(new { @Name = name, @class = "dynamicField" }).WidthLg(formWidth).Append(Html.Bootstrap().Button().Id("ipAddrWebPageButton").Text(buttonText)).Label().LabelText(field.Key.Name).ShowRequiredStar(field.Key.Required)
```

I have tried different things like splitting the line right before or after a dot, also tried adding some @ symbols at the start of a new line, tried looking around for an answer but found absolutely nothing.

I know and have done this kind of method chaining split on multiple lines in regular C#, so I assume it can be done in Razor. Am I wrong in my assumption?
If not, how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it with `()`

```
@(f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.EquipmentItem.Fields[field.Key].FieldValue)
 .Id(field.Key.ID.ToString()).HtmlAttributes(new { @Name = name, @class = "dynamicField" })
 .WidthLg(formWidth).Append(Html.Bootstrap().Button().Id("ipAddrWebPageButton")
 .Text(buttonText)).Label().LabelText(field.Key.Name).ShowRequiredStar(field.Key.Required))
```

Comment: @Rahgooy I love you! I will accept the answer when the time limit restriction is gone, or after lunch. That was so simple but for some reason I could not find an answer with google searches.